# HTML - Give priority to CSS style

Tags: css

I have an HTML that loads two stylesheet:

1. Bootstrap style (`bootstrap.css`)
2. Custom app style (`site.css`)

I have the following code in `bootstrap.css`

```css
.modal-open .modal {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

What do I need to insert into my `site.css` so I give priority to `site.css` style without modifying `bootstrap.css`:

```css
.modal-open .modal {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: #D5D5D5
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should load the `site.css` file after `bootstrap.css` like @luka suggests. This doesn't always guarantee success because the specificity Bootstrap gives some of it's rulesets are really high. It appears in your specific situation, you shouldn't have any problem. But Bootstrap's rulesets intertwine sometimes and there may be something you're not aware of or can't locate that might be preventing your ruleset from succeeding.

In the case of you loading `site.css` after `bootstrap.css` doesn't work, **do not use `!important`**. Instead, double up on your selector:

> ```
> .modal-open.modal-open .modal.modal {
>     overflow-x: hidden;
>     overflow-y: scroll;
>     background-color: #D5D5D5
> }
> ```

According to this [online tool](https://specificity.keegan.st/), the selector above CSS specificity score is 4, while Bootstrap's is a 2. This technique has been 100% for me for years.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than adding `!important`, you can just add the custom style sheet after the bootstrap stylesheet in the `<head>` section of your site:

```
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This way, for any duplicate CSS selectors/properties the `site.css` will override the `bootstrap.css`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `!important` :

```
.modal-open .modal {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    background-color: #D5D5D5 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

1. If the rule is exactly the same - the last rule that exists will take over (so if you link first to the `bootstrap.css` and after it to the `site.css` - the style inside the `site.css` will take.
2. You can add the `!important` (not the best option, but you can do it).
3. You can duplicate the selectors: `.modal-open.modal-open .modal.modal {...}`